# When laptop battery on "High Performance" it stops charging the battery

Tags: laptop, power-supply, battery, power

I'm using an ACER Aspire 5750G and my laptop specs are:

- Proccessor: Intel Core i7-2630QM
- Display: 15,6 LED LCD
- Nvidia GeForce GT 540M - 1GB - CUDA
- Memory: 8GB
- HDD: 750GB
- SSD: 250GB
- Acer Nptity 802.11b/g/a

I have it for around 4 years now. Very strange thing is going on when I play games (like DOTA) or render movies or anything else that uses a lot of my laptop CPU. When this is happening and my laptop battery plan is set to be at "High Performance":

- sometimes my laptop doesn't want to charge; in this case I have to unplug the charger from the laptop and plug it again
- sometimes my AC power light is not on (which means it is not charging) and in order to fix it I have to unplug the charger from the wall and plug it again
- or sometimes it is doing both things at the same time and because my battery is only holding my laptop up and running for about 2-3 mins and if both of the things above happening a lot (which they do) my laptop just shuts down and i have to unplug the charger again in order my laptop to have power and then power it again.

what I have done already to try and fix that issue:

- I given my laptop 3 times to 2 different companies to fix the issue, paid like 50 euro and this issue its still there
- I tried to run the computer without the battery and it does not work. it is still giving me the same problem
- I tried to run the computer with other AC power and it is still giving me the same problem
- I tried with other battery and it does not work as well

Comment: Did you try a different battery?

Comment: yes i also tried a different battery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Your AC adapter isn't supplying enough power.

- On some laptops, the battery will not charge when under full load because there is insufficient power available from the AC adapter. Under load, the processor and GPU can consume most of the power available from the adapter, leaving no power to charge the battery. This is more likely to happen in High Performance mode because faster system operation requires more power.
- Make sure your AC adapter isn't damaged and supplies enough power for your system. If this behavior has only recently started occurring and the adapter has worked before, you may need to replace the AC adapter as power output can degrade over many years of use (electrolytic capacitors don't last forever).
- The AC adapter you showed provides 90 watts. While this matches the supplied AC adapter, it isn't quite enough to power your system under load and charge the battery at the same time. The processor requires up to 45 watts, while the GPU can draw up to 35 watts. You may want to try finding a 120-watt adapter that will work with your system.

Comment: thank you, but i have question. i have tried to run the computer with other AC power (not new, but used from other PC) and it was doing the same problem. My question is if u think i have to buy a new AC adapter and that will fix the issue can i buy a more powerfull AC adapter? What do u think?

Comment: this is my AC adapter right now: http://i01.i.aliimg.com/wsphoto/v0/2023590253_1/NEW-90W-Original-Laptop-AC-Adapter-For-ACER-GATEWAY-HIPRO-HP-A0904A3-19V-4-74A-.jpg

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken it off high performance?? go where your battery icon is. click on it. go to "More power options". are you on balanced? go to change plan settings. from there go to "change advanced power settings" from there there's a bar that should be selected as "High performance" Change it back to "balanced." And see if that fixes your issue hope this helps your battery problem. If not. Try a new charger? Best keep it on balanced. Should work better.